# Azure SQL DB migration from Visual Studio raises collation error

Tags: azure-sql-database, collation, entity-framework, visual-studio

I want to run a migration in my Azure hosted database. The migration works perfect in several local machines. When I try targeting the Azure database it raises the following exception:

> Column X is not of same collation as referencing column Y in foreign
>   key Z.

I´m trying to run the migration from VS 2015 package manager console as I do with the development machines.

Is this the correct approach to run migrations in the Azure DB? I´m missing something?

I did some research and got that Azure DB collation is `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` and Local machine´s DB is `Modern_Spanish_CI_AS`

I don't want to move data from one database to the other so this is not the real problem. I think the problem came from Visual Studio because it is applying the `Modern_Spanish_CI_AS` to all the SQL scripts that is running.

How can I change this option?

I´m working with asp.net mvc 5 and EntityFramework code-first